# Sliding Window Algorithm: Search exact entity in DBpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am using a sliding window algorithm to search URI in DBpedia. With keyword strings entered, I separate them into small clusters and then search on DBpedia.

Example:

Keyword: `Actor of the film titanic`

=>Separate them into:
`Actor of the`, `Actor of`, `Actor`, `of the film`, `of the`, `of`, `the film Titanic,` `the movie`, `the`, `film titanic`, `movie`, `titanic`

Question: How can I search for exactly the entities named as keywords (phrases analyzed above) included using SPARQL?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I notice that you're doing more than *splitting* the original search-term -- as you have `movie` and `Titanic` (capital `T`) in your separated set, but these do not appear in the original. That makes your question rather bigger than it first appears -- and re-invents several more wheels.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are so many question answering systems out now for Linked Data and evaluated against DBpedia - I don't understand why you want to reinvent the wheel.
2. SPARQL query by using what? You can match the `rdfs:label` values, e.g.

   `SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {?s rdfs:label "KEYWORD"@en .}`

but most QA systems are using a pre-computed fulltext index based on Lucene or the like. At least, that's how we did it in our QA project(s).

Comment: Thanks so much. I used query below:
SELECT distinct ?s WHERE {
?s rdfs:label "+searchText+"@en."
?s foaf:name "+searchText+"@en."
?s foaf:givenName
"+searchText+"@en."
...
}